# Map properties to another object in Swift

Tags: swift

let's say I have a struct like so

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
  var bool1: Bool? = false
  var bool2: Bool
  var whateverElse: Date
  var andThis: String?
}
```

Now that struct has some 30 properties and from time to time I need to add more of them.

In part of the logic of the app, I need to reset **only boolean** properties from another instance of the same struct, so I have a boring method like so:

```
func resetToValues(_ from: MyStruct) {
  self.bool1 = from.bool1
  self.bool2 = from.bool2
}
```

Note that `whateverElse` and `andThis` are not reset.
Every time I add a property, I have to add a line to this method which is annoying.

Is there some way to automate it such that only `Bool` and `Bool?` properties are reset?

I thought of getting at `CodingKeys` and iterating over them, but unfortunately since I can't get a lot out of `Mirror.Child` nor get a `KeyPath` by string I am stuck in that I can't determine what is Bool and what is not.

Answer (score 2):

you can use sorcery to generate code:
https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery

1. Install Sourcery
2. Add template.stencil file:

The template file for you could be:

```
import Foundation

{% for type in types %}
extension {{type.name}} {
    mutating func reset(with other: {{type.name}}) {
        {% for variable in type.storedVariables %}
        {% if variable.typeName|hasPrefix:"Bool" %}
        self.{{variable}} = other.{{variable}}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    }
}
{% endfor %}
```

3. Add new script to build phase:

   sourcery --sources <path.to.your.struct> --templates <path.to.stencil> --output <path.to.output>
4. Build and add output file to your project (only for the first time)